# Motorcycle paint help

Tags: motorcycle, paint-clearcoat

I am repainting my motorcycle with some spray cans and I have painted the tank, front fender and rear fender pieces all with the same primer, same color, and same clear coat successfully. A little bit ago the side of my tank got some cosmetic damage so I sanded it back, re-primed it, re-painted it and then coated it with the same exact clearcoat that worked the first time and it cracked on me. I figured that I had some type of surface contamination that the clear didn't adhear to so I sanded it back and re-primed and painted then cleaned and degreased it only to have this cracking happen a second time. Third time I repeated the same steps but then sanded the color lightly with 1000 grit to try to give the clear topcoat something to grip. Then I, again cleaned and degreased it to a point you could eat off it and this cracking happens again! Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm at the point I'm wanting to sell my bike this is frustrating me so much.

[image]

Comment: Did you remove all the old coats of paint back to the metal?

Comment: Yes, each time I repainted I stripped it all the way back

Comment: Did you change the amount of time between coats.

Comment: Nope same time between coats. The cans say to wait 48 hours to fully cure and I waited 72 between each coat

Comment: You should be able to tell which layers are reacting by sanding it down slightly and seeing which colours appear.  You could try a few tests spraying clear coat on base colour without primer and also clear coat on primer to see which react.  If all the variables are the same, it doesn’t make sense for it to work once but then react.

Comment: Are they the original cans that you used, or new cans of the same manufacturer?  Maybe they have changed the formula slightly?

Comment: I know it's the clear that's reacting weird, the thing I don't understand is the fact that I originally painted the whole tank with the exact same cans using the exact same prep work and it worked perfectly. I haven't changed anything but it keep peeling on me. They're the same cans as I originally used

Comment: It won’t be just the clear coat.  Two of the layers are reacting together.  You mayfind that changing the primer will fix the issue.  You can also buy isolator coats that stop paint layers reacting.

Comment: I guess I'm just dumbfounded that this didn't happen when I originally painted the tank using the exact same primer, color and clear